# how to unhide my vertices?

Tags: modeling

[image] I'm following Guru's donut tutorial to make a donut. In part 4, Guru said he had clicked the left button and press G to unreal vertices. But the mesh will just move if I do that. Any ways can I apply to reveal them on the surface?

Comment: @HrishavSaha Alt+G resets the location in _Object Mode_ and I think it does nothing in _Edit Mode_ as far as I know. What Blender Guru presses is Alt+Z, this enables the x-ray in both _Object Mode_ and _Edit Mode_. Some people pronounce Z as zed, some as zee.

Comment: God, Im so sorry. I meant Alt+Z. Im an idiot